# Is there any Service Level Agreement (SLA) for Amazon SQS? For example, its uptime

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-sqs

As subject. I try to move from RabbitMQ to SQS. 
Want to know whether there is any uptime guarantee or alike. 
All I can find is that, Amazon SQS stores messages in a distributed storage across all availability zones in a given region. 
Does that imply, SQS is as reliable as an AWS region or 99.9% (or better) most of the time?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is now an SLA available for SQS: https://aws.amazon.com/messaging/sla/

In particular, "AWS will use commercially reasonable efforts to make [SQS] available with a Monthly Uptime Percentage ... of at least 99.9%"

Answer (score 4):

There is no SLA for Amazon SQS.

SLAs can generally be accessed at: `http://aws.amazon.com/<service>/sla`

Comment: @ScottCate There is no SLA for Amazon SQS.

Comment: Do any services have sla's besides s3?

Comment: @TimothyGonzalez Do a Google search for `site:aws.amazon.com sla`.

Comment: Is there any historical data about the reliability of SQS? e.g. "in the last year, it was reliable for 99.9%" or whatever